How are realism, determinism, counter factual definiteness and non-contextuality related?
I have come across these terms when trying to understand the EPR paradox and its resolution. I have found that they are often used interchangeably, but when I look up their official definitions, I find that they are referring to different but closely related concepts. Are there well established logical relationships among them (as in, is one conditioned on, implied by, or equivalent to another)? Could the similarities and differences among them be illustrated using the EPR experiment as an example?

What is CFD in this context?

Thanks for the feedback. I was referring to counter factual definiteness.

A paradox is the name for a situation in which improper reasoning leads to contradictions. I am not sure that the EPR paper is much of a paradox. It is not a particularly good analysis of the physics of entangled systems, though. That can be done in roughly two sentences using relativity.

@FlatterMann could you please elaborate on why it's not a good analysis? I have heard before that the EPR experiment is considered incorrect by some, but I'm not familiar with why.

It's not incorrect, it just doesn't use the actual ingredient that causes the structure of quantum mechanics: relativity. In other words, it formulates the correct question, but then the paper doesn't do anything to solve it. It basically just reiterates "the mystery".  To me the most curious aspect of EPR is why three relativists like Einstein. Podolsky and Rosen didn't notice that this was relativity at work. That is a science history question and not a physics question, though.

According to my understanding, relativity isn't implicit in quantum mechanics. The dirac equation brought relativity into the picture for the first time but it was formulated by introducing a separated understanding of relativity into a hamiltonian. So could you please elaborate on how relativity causes the structure of quantum mechanics?
